# box-sizing:border-box with width < padding

Tags: html, css

As I understand [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/), `box-sizing:border-box` makes it so that

```
width = border-left-width + padding-left + <free space> + padding-right + border-right-width
```

At least, that is exactly what happens if I set

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div>170px free space</div>
```

So, from my understanding, `width` defines the "overall width" of the element. However, if the width is smaller than the sum of paddings+border-widths, weird things happen:

```css
div, span, input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0; /* <= */
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<br>
<span></span>
<br>
<input>
```

Divs behave as expected, spans seem to show everything "left" from the "<free space>", and inputs show everything (and just have a 0px "<free space>").

*What explains this behavior?*

---

*Edit:* `span{display:block}` makes the span behave as the div, which makes it at least a bit understandable. But `input{display:block}` does not have the same effect. Why?

```css
div, span, input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  display: block; /* <= */
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 5px solid green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid green;
  background: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<br>
<span></span>
<br>
<input>
```

Comment: In Safari, with `display:block` set on each tag, the element is completely gone, whereas with `display:inline` set, it shows the padding and border with no free space.

When `display` is not set to `block` or is set to `inline`, it appears to be overriding `box-sizing` which is leaving the padding and border in there, even though you set a width of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add a height to the elements you will see they are all the same.

```css
div, span, input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: solid green;
  border-width: 0 5px 0 5px;
  background: #ebebeb;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<br>
<span></span>
<br>
<input>
```

the "element" itself is 0 width, shown by the blue box

padding is 10px on both sides

border is 5px on both sides

resulting in a total box-sizing width of 30px

[image]

Comment: Ok, so all three have the same width, and just `input`s appear to have an "intrinsic" height (the other two have a height of `0`). Leaves me with the question: why don't they all have a width of `0` (but instead the sum of their paddings/border-widths)?

Comment: the elements have a width of 0
padding of 10px on each side
border of 5px on each side
resulting in a total box-sizing width of 30px

chrome has a good visualization of this in dev tools at the bottom of the "styles" tab

Comment: Sure. However looking at the same visualization for my first example (`width:200px`), the width of the "element itself" appears as `170px`, whereas in your example `width:0` results in `0`. Then, the `<span>` in my second example has a width of the "element itself" of `-30px` (but shows the 5px border-left and the 10px padding-left). This all does not fit in my mental model of box-sizing... Where am I wrong? (thank you for your patience, by the way!)

Comment: border-box makes it so that the outside of the border is considered the outside bounds of the element. thats why in the 200px example, the borders and padding take up the "inner" space.  in the second example with width 0, the width of the element is 0 but the borders and padding are still set, and they need to take up space, and since the borders are the outer most thing, they intern make the total element wider than 0px, does that make sense?

Comment: So, in the end with `box-sizing:border-box` the width of the "outside bounds" of the element will be the `width` property, but will not be smaller than the sum of borders and paddings (i.e. `offsetWidth = max(width, borders + paddings)`). I can live with that. Thank you!